# Order of entire function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that

$$1)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(z)=\frac{\Gamma^2(1+d)}{\Gamma(1+d+z)\Gamma(1+d-z)}, \ \ d\in\mathbb R$$
$$2)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ f(z)=\frac{\Gamma^2(1+\bar d)}{\Gamma(1+\bar d+z)\Gamma(1+\bar d-z)}, \ \ \bar d\in\mathbb C$$

is entire of order 1 for, respectively $d>-1$ and $\Re(\bar d)>-1$. My approach for (1):

$$f(z)=\Gamma^2(1+d)\ C(d,z)\ \prod_n \left(1+\frac{1+d+z}{n}\right) \left(1+\frac{1+d-z}{n}\right)$$

where we have used the definition of Gamma function

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=z e^{\gamma z}\prod_n \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}$$

($\gamma$ Euler's constant); $f(z)$ has zero at $z=\pm(n+1+d)$.

$$\sum_n \frac{1}{|n+1+d|^\alpha}$$

the greatest lower bound of positive numbers $\alpha$ for which the previous series is convergent is $\rho=1$ that is the order of entire function (1).

In reality, this would be the definition of exponent of convergence but it coincides with the order of entire functions for the canonical products.

My approach for (2)

$$f(z)=\Gamma^2(1+\bar d)\ C(\bar d,z)\ \prod_n \left(1+\frac{1+\bar d+z}{n}\right) \left(1+\frac{1+\bar d-z}{n}\right)$$ and $f(z)$ has zero at $z=\pm(n+1+d)$.

$$\sum_n \frac{1}{|n+1+\bar d|^\alpha}=\sum_n \frac{1}{\left(\left(n+1+\Re(\bar d)\right)^2+\Im^2(\bar d)\right)^{\alpha/2}}$$

the greatest lower bound of positive numbers $\alpha$ for which the previous series is convergent is $\rho=1$ that is the order of entire function (2).

Is my procedure right? I made ​​a mistake?